# Java - Convert list of variables to map of variable name to variable value

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose I have a few variables:

```
public void foo() {
    String name = "Bob";
    String gender = "Male";
    Integer age = 6;
    String address = "some address";
}
```

How can I turn them into a `Map<String, Object>` like

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("name", name);
map.put("gender", gender);
map.put("age", age);
map.put("address", address);
```

other than manually inserting them into the map. Can this be done using Reflection?

Comment: What do you really need? A map or an String in that format?

Comment: You're trying to write a JSon?

Comment: Just edited my question, it has nothing to do with Json, I just need a map :)

Comment: @WoLfPwNeR You just can't do that. `name`, `gender` etc are local variables, and reflection can't be used for local variables. If they were fields it would be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to manually put them into a map. It is not possible to use reflection to find the names or values of local variables.

Answer (score 3):

Dont re invent the wheel
use Json libraries and parse your objects

## Example (using Gson...):

```
public class GenericTypeData {
    private String name = "Bob";
    private String gender = "Male";
    private int age = 6;
    private String address = "some address";
    
    public GenericTypeData( ) {
        this.name = "Bob";
        this.gender = "Male";
        this.age = 6;
        this.address = "some address";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Gson().ToJson(this, GenericTypeData.class));
    }

}
```

you will get a json like

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "gender": "Male",
    "age": 6,
    "address": "some address", 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your variables are fixed for a class to convert into map then you can convert them into a json.

You can first prepare your object containing variables and then use `toJson()` method to convert it into the format as you specified in your question.

This [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) may help for usage of `toJson()` method from `google gson library`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in String, you can use the method [ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(Object, ToStringStyle)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html#toString(java.lang.Object,%20org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle)) from [Apache Commons Lang.](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) Using `JSON_STYLE`.